# how to write LINQ Query on three columns with a different value on each one

Tags: linq

I'm new to this and this is my first question.

So far I have this, but it takes a long time to get the record:

```
    public string BuscarPedimento(string patente, string pedimento2, string aduana)
    {
        using (var context = new DataStage3Context())
        {
            DsPedimentos pedimento = context.DsPedimentos.FirstOrDefault(p => (p.Patente == patente & p.AduanaDespacho == aduana & p.Pedimento == pedimento2));
            if (pedimento == null)
                return "";
            else
                return Convert.ToString(pedimento.Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you use `&` instead of `&&`?

Comment: The behavior is correct, it's simply a long-running operation on the database?  In that case you probably want to debug the database.  I'm not sure how to get the actual resulting SQL query from the DB context (Google can help with that), but you can run a SQL Profiler against your database to capture the query being executed.  From there, use the database management tools to get the query plan / execution path of your query.  See where the performance is going.  You may need to better index the table.

Comment: Thanks David. I think the problem is the index.

Comment: I agree with the Index part have you tried creating indexes in the columns you're resting here?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The problem was the single ampersand, two were needad.